# My query returns single record when use sum function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following table structure, and relationship is one `purchase_order` has many `purchase_order_detail` and one `purchase_order_detail` has many `delivery_order`;
**purchase_order**

```
+-------------------+-------------------------+
| purchase_order_id | purchase_order          |
+-------------------+-------------------------+
|                29 | Dell Computer 000001256 |
|                31 | Dell Computer 000001257 |
+-------------------+-------------------------+
```

**purchase_order_detail**

```
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------+
| purchase_order_detail_id | purchase_order_id | item_id | ordered_quantity |
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------+
|                       26 |                29 |     279 |              100 |
|                       27 |                29 |     286 |              100 |
|                       28 |                29 |     287 |              100 |
|                       29 |                31 |     279 |               75 |
|                       30 |                31 |     286 |               85 |
+--------------------------+-------------------+---------+------------------+
```

**delivery_order**

```
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
| delivery_order_id | purchase_order_detail_id | recieved_quantity |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
|                30 |                       26 |                50 |
|                31 |                       27 |                50 |
|                32 |                       28 |                50 |
|                33 |                       29 |                25 |
|                34 |                       30 |                35 |
+-------------------+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

i want to get purchase_order and total recieved quantity for a item_id in purchase_order_detail table, 
i write this query,, but it returns incorrect record

```
SELECT po.created_on, po.purchase_order_id, po.purchase_order, i.item_name, SUM( do.recieved_quantity ) AS quantity
FROM purchase_order po, purchase_order_detail pod, delivery_order do , item i
WHERE i.item_id = pod.item_id
AND po.purchase_order_id = pod.purchase_order_id
AND pod.purchase_order_detail_id = do.purchase_order_detail_id
AND pod.item_id =286

+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+
| created_on          | purchase_order_id | purchase_order          | item_name | quantity |
+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+
| 2015-02-23 13:49:40 |                29 | Dell Computer 000001256 | Lenovo    |       85 |
+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+
```

as you can see that item_id 286 is against two purchase_orders.

Comment: Add "group by" to your query

Answer (score 3):

You miss the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT po.created_on, po.purchase_order_id, po.purchase_order, i.item_name, SUM( do.recieved_quantity ) AS quantity
FROM purchase_order po, purchase_order_detail pod, delivery_order do , item i
WHERE i.item_id = pod.item_id
AND po.purchase_order_id = pod.purchase_order_id
AND pod.purchase_order_detail_id = do.purchase_order_detail_id
AND pod.item_id =286
group by po.created_on, po.purchase_order_id, po.purchase_order, i.item_name
```